# Remove the Columns from testing data if the column is not present in training data - R

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One is a training data frame and another one is a testing data frame. There are so many columns inside it. Therefore, deleting the columns through hard coding is not an option.

I am looking for a function that will delete the columns in testing data if it not there in the training data.

For Example

```
Train_data1<- read.table(text = "
A B C D
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
1 3 3 0", header = TRUE)
```

I am removing the A row from the Training data frame, as it doesn't affect the model.

```
Train_data <- read.table(text = "
 B C D
 1 1 0
 1 1 1
 2 2 2
 3 3 0", header = TRUE)
```

Therefore because A column is not there in the Training data, I don't want that to be in the testing data as well.

```
testing data <- read.table(text = "
 B C D
 1 1 0", header = TRUE)
```

Any Solutions to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test <- data.frame(A=1, B=1, C=1, D=1)
train <- data.frame(A=1, B=1)

testNew <- test[, colnames(train)]
testNew
#   A B
# 1 1 1
```

Comment: I was going to answer using `intersect`, but this answer is more straightforward.